# CakePHP display parent category and subcategory in a ul

Tags: cakephp, categories

I have a index page category 
that i want show all parent-catagory and it's sub-category as below,
How do it?
http://i.upanh.com/rndntq

Comment: And the code you tried is...?

Comment: [Open your IDE. Start typing. Press `Ctrl + S`. Open up your browser. Navigate to your localhost where your project is located. **repeat**. After 5 or 10 shots, post your code and we can help you :)](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: ^^
thnks for commenting
in CategoriesController
<code>
    public function index() {
        $this->Category->recursive = 0;
        //$this->set('categories', $this->paginate());
        $CategoryList = $this->Category->generateTreeList(null, null, null, '-');
        $this->set(compact('CategoryList'));
    }
</code>
in View
<code>
<?php debug($CategoryList); ?>
</code>
with debug i can show all categories and it's sub-category
but i can show it like that i has capture <http://i.upanh.com/rndntq>

Answer (score 0):

SELECT c1.cat_id as childID, c1.cat_name ChildName, c2.cat_name as ParentName
from category c1
LEFT OUTER JOIN category c2
ON c1.parent = c2.cat_id